# get database postgresql backup from disk

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to have my **postgresql** database on disk (Ubuntu 14.04); how can I set this up and access the data? I have to use ftp to get files; I don't know where to search.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html

Comment: I can't do nothing in the server, I just looking for a way to get the data (in /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main) and with this get my database

Comment: `pg_basebackup` is a client application.

Comment: Yes but I can just get the data from /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main and nothing else on this server (no ssh, no command "pg_basebackup")

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete backup of the database via FTP, you'll have to [follow the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP). Basically, first you call `pg_start_backup`, then you get the data directory, then you call `pg_stop_backup`, then you get all WAL archives.

You have to run recovery on the backup before you can access it.